# How to make filter on an output based on string lines?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, ash

I have the following output

```
$ mycommand
1=aaa
1=eee
12=cccc
15=bbb
```

And I have a string `str` containing:

```
eee
cccc
```

and I want to display only lines which contains string exist in the string lines

So my out put will be:

```
$ mycommand | use_awk_or_sed_or_any_command
1=eee
12=cccc
```

Comment: How do you mean "string 'str' containing ...?"

Answer (score 2):

If you store the strings in a file, you can use `grep` with its `-f` option:

```
$ cat  search
eee
cccc

$ grep -wf search file
1=eee
12=cccc
```

You might also need the `-F` option if your strings contain special characters like `.`, `$` etc.

Comment: it works if I m using files. But How I can make it work if my output is from command and the search string is a shell variable

Answer (score 2):

Say your command is `echo -e "1=aaa\n1=eee\n12=cccc\n15=bbb"`, you could do

```
echo -e "1=aaa\n1=eee\n12=cccc\n15=bbb" | grep -wE "$(sed  'N;s/\n/|/' <<<"$str")"
```

The `sed` command simply replaces the newline (`\n`) with `|` which is used by `grep -E` (for extended regular expressions) to separate multiple patterns. This means that the `grep` will print lines matching *either* `eee` *or* `cccc`. The `w` ensures that the match is of an entire word, so that things like `eeeeee` will not be matched.